# Magento 2: I need to initialize the object manager out of foreach loop

Tags: magento2

I need to initialize the object manager out of for each loop.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Abc\Mkt\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
    class Masssync extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{
        /**
         * Masssync Action for Mass Sync of customer with Marketo 
         * @return Void   
         * */
        protected $_objectManager;
        protected $_api;
        protected $scopeConfig;
        public function __construct(Orderapi $Api, ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper, \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerData,\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager, \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context)
        {

            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
            $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper; 
            $this->customerData = $customerData; 
            $this->modelData = $modelData; 
            $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
        public function execute(){

                    $customerIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam("selected");
                     foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
                                $item = $this->_objectManager->create('\Abc\Mkt\Model\Data');
                                $customer = $this->customerData->load($customerId);
                                $item->setCustomerId($customerId);
                                $item->setSyncWithMarketo(1);
                                $item->save();  
                                $data['FirstName'] = $customer->getFirstname();
                                $data['LastName'] = $customer->getLastname();
                                $data['Email'] = $customer->getEmail();         
                                $allfield = array("email");
                                array_push($mergeData,$data);
                        }

                }
        }
```

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object manager is not recommended in Magento.
So the actual implementation should be like this:

```
protected $modelData;
public function __construct(
    Orderapi $Api,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerData,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Abc\Mkt\Model\Data $modelData
)
{

    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    $this->customerData = $customerData;
    $this->modelData = $modelData;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    $this->modelData = $modelData;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    $customerIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam("selected");
    foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
        $item = clone $this->modelData;
        $customer = $this->customerData->load($customerId);
        $item->setCustomerId($customerId);
        $item->setSyncWithMarketo(1);
        $item->save();  
        $data['FirstName'] = $customer->getFirstname();
        $data['LastName'] = $customer->getLastname();
        $data['Email'] = $customer->getEmail();         
        $allfield = array("email");
        array_push($mergeData,$data);
    }

}
```

But still, if you want to use object manager, you can do it by this:

```
$itemObj = $this->_objectManager->create('\Abc\Mkt\Model\Data');
foreach ($customerIds as $customerId)
{
    $item = clone $itemObj;
    $customer = $this->customerData->load($customerId);
    $item->setCustomerId($customerId);
    $item->setSyncWithMarketo(1);
    $item->save();  
    $data['FirstName'] = $customer->getFirstname();
    $data['LastName'] = $customer->getLastname();
    $data['Email'] = $customer->getEmail();         
    $allfield = array("email");
    array_push($mergeData,$data);
}
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: This is working for me

Comment: Can you please tell me? why we use clone @shoaib?

Comment: Because you want to use same object for all the customers and you want to make new object every time, so clone will copy your object to new one and you can use it separately.

Comment: Thankyou so much for clarification